# How to do split and left join in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I work with toad for oracle and I have a database with multiple associations(1-n).
I want to associate the varchar column (example :1,2,3) in table with the int (id)(example : 1) column of the other table . I am creating a view for this operation in database, but the outer apply and cross apply do not work.

Also did not work in the dbo.split command found in sql.

How can do it?

```
SELECT
      a.ID AS ID,
      a.ADI_NUMARASI AS aNAME,
      c.ID AS CODEID,   
      c.VALUE AS cVALUE   
 FROM  CUSTOMER a OUTER APPLY [dbo].[Split](a.TypeIDs, ',') Types 
LEFT JOIN CODE c ON c.ID= Types.Item  AND c.DOMAINID = a.DOMAINID
```

Example tables

```
table CUSTOMER                                     table CODE
 ID | ADI_NUMARASI | TYPEIDS |DOMAINID         ID | DOMAINID | VALUE
 1      TEST1        1,2,3     1                1      1        XXX
                                                2      1        YYY
                                                3      2        ZZZ
                                                3      1        KKK
```

expected result

```
 ID | aNAME | CODEID | cVALUE
 1    TEST1      1       XXX
 1    TEST1      2       YYY
 1    TEST1      3       KKK
```

Comment: Can you give sample input data and expected result?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow please proves some tables and required output.

Comment: are you sure that you are using oracle and not mssql? `split`is not a standard Oracle function

Comment: I use split in mysql but I don't know how to do split in oracle.
How can do split in oracle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT cu.ID , cu.ADI_NUMARASI , co.ID , co.VALUE
FROM 
(
  SELECT id,ADI_NUMARASI,TYPEIDS,DOMAINID,
  regexp_substr(TYPEIDS,'[^,]+', 1, level) typeidsnew 
  FROM Customer 
  GROUP BY id,ADI_NUMARASI,TYPEIDS,DOMAINID,
  regexp_substr(TYPEIDS, '[^,]+', 1, level)
  connect by regexp_substr(TYPEIDS, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
) cu 
LEFT JOIN Code co ON cu.typeidsnew = co.ID
AND cu.DomainId = co.domainId 
ORDER BY cu.ID,co.ID
```

Output: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/177e8/1

Comment: Try now! @GülÖZCAN

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
WITH splitedValues as (SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TYPEIDS, '[^,]+', 1, level)) as TYPEID 
                             , ADI_NUMARASI                                 
                             , DOMAINID
                        FROM CUSTOMER
                      CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(TYPEIDS, '[^,]+'))
select * 
  from splitedValues s 
  join code c on s.TYPEID = c.id and s.domainid =  c.domainid
```